# scheduled tasks via cmd / quoting Problem

Tags: batch-file, cmd, double-quotes, windows-task-scheduler, single-quotes

I've a problem with quotes when creating scheduled tasks over command line.
I try to create a task which starts a batch script and passes some parameters to it.
The command looks like following:

```
 SCHTASKS /CREATE /RU "MyUserName" /SC ONCE /ST 00:00 /TN "TestTask" /TR "D:\Thats\my\script.bat 'P:\aram\one' 'P:\aram\two\'" /IT /F
```

Now, the task gets created but if I check it via

```
CHTASKS /query /TN "TestTask" /FO List /V
```

I get following info:

```
D:\Thats\my\script.bat "P:\aram\one" "P:\aram\two\'
```

instead of following info:

```
D:\Thats\my\script.bat "P:\aram\one" "P:\aram\two\"
```

The second **info** has a double high quote at the end and the first one not.
May some one asks what kind of path that is which ends with a slash, but I do need it for a script.

My second question is why the task scheduler seems to change every single quotes into double quotes.

Comment: The question I'd like you to answer is, why are you terminating an argument with a backward slash? I ask because it is generally a separator, not a terminator. Do not make the common mistake of thinking that including one somehow distinguishes it as a directory rather that a file. Did you try escaping the backward slash with another backward slash?

Comment: @Compo: Yeah, the reason of trailing backward slash was to highlight that it´s a directory rather than a file as you said. I tried then to modify my command as suggested from @Mofi to: `%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /Create /RU "MyUserName" /SC ONCE /ST 00:00 /TN "TestTask" /TR "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"D:\Thats\my\script.bat\" \"P:\aram\one\" \"P:\aram\two\\\"" /IT /F` and it worked as expected.`
@Mofi: I only wan´t to trigger the task manually, so `WARNING: Task may not run because /ST is earlier than current time.` is not a problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Untested]

I believe that the backslash before the single-quote is **escaping** that single-quote, as indicated by your results (actual ends single-quote, expected double)

So - I'd try doubling that backslash so that it is backslash that is escaped.